# Entanglement in the Born-Oppenheimer approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-entanglement, born-oppenheimer-approximation

Consider a scenario where we aim to model an atom as a system consisting of two components: the nucleus and the valence electron.

In this approach, we simulate the behavior of the electron within the potential field generated by the nucleus for one time step. Then, in the subsequent time step, we simulate the behavior of the nucleus within the potential field generated by the electron. Now, the question arises: Could this alternating simulation process result in entanglement between the nucleus and the electron?

Intuitively, it seems unlikely that entanglement would emerge from this approach. By treating the nucleus and the electron as separate entities and merely exchanging information between the two simulations, we might not capture the complex correlations and quantum effects that can give rise to entanglement. Is that correct? Is there a more formal argument for this?

Comment: On what (observable) basis would you think they could be entangled?  Momentum, spin, etc.?  There would need to be something conserved that is also in a superposition.

Comment: @DrChinese Probably spin, but I'm more concerned with whether entanglement is even possible by looking at the systems separately and exchanging information between them.